# MYSQL SELECT query with WHERE and LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this MYSQL query?  It is generating an error

```
SELECT * WHERE column1 = '1055 West Joppa Road' FROM table1 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: wrong order for `where` and `from`. also. nobody here is psychic, if you get an error, PUT THE ERROR IN THE QUESTION.

Comment: Usually, MySQL issues a *particular* error message, with an error number and some text, rather than some *vague* error.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = '1055 West Joppa Road' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE column1 = '1055 West Joppa Road'  LIMIT 1;
```

Put your table name after `*`